# Narrow Down a Shop Page Results Based on a Product Tag in WooCommerce

Tags: categories, wp-query, plugins

I have a shop page that displays a product (chairs) for a retailer in multiple cities. Each city is a tag for each product. What I want to be able to do is narrow down a category page like (chairs) or a shop page to only show product from that city.

Is there a way to filter the product results?

Answer (score 2):

I passed query strings to the URL of the category page to display the tags within that category.  This is what I did to solve the same problem

```
function displayLocationDropdown() {
if(!is_product_tag()){
    $html = '';
    $html .= '<form class="location-select" method="post">';
    $html .= '<select id="location-selector" name="location" class="location">';

    $tag = wp_tag_cloud( array(
        'format' => 'array',
        'taxonomy' => 'product_tag' 
    ) );
    $page_path = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    $page_url = site_url() . $page_path;
    $url_parts = parse_url($page_url);
    $constructed_url = $url_parts['scheme'] . '://' . $url_parts['host'] . (isset($url_parts['path'])?$url_parts['path']:'');

    $html .= '<option value="#">--Select Location--</option>';

    foreach($tag as $tagkey => $tagvalue)
    {
        $cleanedup = strip_tags($tagvalue);
        $tag_info = get_term_by('name', $cleanedup, 'product_tag', 'ARRAY_A');
        $tag_slug = $tag_info['slug'];
        if(isset($_GET['product_tag'])) {
            $value_url = $constructed_url . '?product_tag=' . $tag_slug;
        } else {
            $value_url = $page_url . '?product_tag=' . $tag_slug;
        }
        $html .= '<option value="' . $value_url . '">' . $cleanedup . '</option>';
    }
    $html .= '<option value="' . $constructed_url . '">View All Locations</option>';

    $html .= '</select>';
    $html .= '</form>';

    echo $html;
}
}
add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'displayLocationDropdown', 40);
```

Then I enqueued the following jQuery to handle loading the URLs when the dropdown is selected.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#location-selector").change(function() {
        location = jQuery("#location-selector option:selected").val();
    });
});
```

I am still looking to refine this, so I will update if I come up with anything better.